# Business Name to NAICS Code Mapping

Tags: government, uses-of-open-data, business, geocoding

I am looking for a way to map business name + address to NAICS code. Found few government sites like follows:

- http://www.thinkkentucky.com/kyedc/kpdf/All_Facilities_Alpha.pdf
- http://www.rcgov.us/Portals/0/Departments/BSC/Documents/2016_BL_Alpha%202016-12-14.pdf
- http://www.muncie.com/Site-Selection-Data/Industrial-Directory.aspx

Can someone recommend a more centralized place where similar lists could be found across US?

Comment: Random guess: the IRS is interested in this, so they may have something: poke around for EINs and TINs. However, since many sole proprietorships use the owner's SSN for tax id, this may not be super helpful finding smaller businesses.

Comment: Interesting idea. Found also this https://github.com/datasets/edgar - which maps public companies to SIC code (potentially convertible to NAICS).

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment. What I've found:

- http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx has downloadable lists of publicly traded companies on three major exchanges (including NASDAQ itself). The CSV files include "Sector" and "Industry", but neither SIC nor NAICS codes.
- https://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/ appears to be the "home page" for NAICS for the census. There's a lot of good information there, including https://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/concordances/concordances.html which converts from SIC to NAICS (and between various versions of NAICS).
- As question 4 of https://www.sec.gov/oiea/Article/edgarguide.html#P130_16535 notes however, "the SEC uses neither all SIC codes nor the North American Industry Classification System (NAICS) codes adopted by the Office of Management and Budget in 1997", so this is imperfect.
- [NAICS Site](https://www.naics.com/search/)
- [NAICS on blm.gov](https://www.bls.gov/bls/naics.htm)
- [Census Geocoder](https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/)
- The github link you found looks interesting, though I don't think it contains any data - just instructions/code on how to get data. Unfortunately, some of the links in the README.md appear broken, but mass downloading the SEC's archive files may suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Relativity6 API service to classify business with NAICs, just using business name and address. The system will perform a real-time consulting with the help of an IA to classify the business.

https://www.relativity6.com/

Disclaimer: I work for Relativity6.