# SIC code for company name

Tags: data-request, usa, companies

Can any one please suggestion me where can I get SIC ([Standard Industry Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Industrial_Classification)) code for US based companies. Have list of US - based companies name and web site info, addition to it - in want of SIC code. It would be great if i get free data set. You suggestion and info would help me a lot...

Comment: You are on an international website. Please [edit] your question and tell us what SIC codes are (preferably with a link), for what countries and in what format you want them. You should [read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like)

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/business-name-to-naics-code-mapping may or may not be helpful

Comment: What countries you are interested in?

Comment: @marfi am looking for US based companies...

Answer (score 2):

I may be misreading the question, but it sounds like you have a set of company data and are looking to grab SIC codes based on this. This may not be possible using company names alone, but working on two assumptions:

1. That you are looking for UK limited company data
2. That you have the company numbers

You can request the relevant data from Companies House at data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/[URI], where [URI] is the company number e.g. 02495927. You can get the data as RDF, JSON, XML, HTML, CSV or YAML by appending the relevant extension, so http://data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/02495927.rdf grabs the relevant data (including SIC code) for that company in RDF format. How you then extract that and combine it with your own data is left as an exercise for the reader...

If, however, you are looking for a large set of company data (including SIC codes) to play about with, you can grab the current complete Companies House dataset at http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_output.html

Comment: Dear friend, thank you for your valuable data and time. But have already got data from companieshouse.gov.uk - for UK companies have collected SIC code. Am looking for US based companies.  Any idea or suggestion for US companies would be much helpful for me....

Comment: Afraid I don't know much about US company data, but the answer just below mine looks like it should help

Answer (score 2):

For US companies, especially public ones you can use the Unigraph API, here is [a sample query](http://try.unigraph.rocks/?q=%7B%0A%20%20subjects(property%3A%20%22label%22%2C%20text%3A%20%22Microsoft%22%2C%20lang%3A%20%22en%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20industry%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20us_sic_code_id%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A) how to the get Microsoft's SIC:

```
{subjects(property: "label", text: "Microsoft", lang: "en") {
    industry {us_sic_code_id}}}
```

What is does is it starts to traverse the graph by the name (label) of Microsoft. When it finds the node with that name it goes into its industry and fetches its code.

Replace Microsoft with any US company of your choice and try it yourself.

From the [sources available in Unigraph](https://unigraph.io/datasets/) by far SEC's EDGAR is the biggest supplier of such codes. Wikidata is second, freebase third.